# Verifying syntax of Pre-Order Binary Search Tree expression

Tags: java

Hey guys so for an assignment I have to read in a user input In-Order binary search tree expression like this: "(a(g))" where 'a' is the root and 'g' is the left child of 'a'. I am stuck trying to ensure correct syntax. For example if (a(g) is entered, it is incorrect syntax because 'a' doesn't have its right closing parentheses. Likewise, if (ab(g)) is input that is also incorrect because there should only be one alphanumeric character per pair of parenthesis. I have code that verifies the correct amount of parenthesis, but I am stuck trying to ensure that each pair of parenthesis contains only one alphanumeric character. This is what I have so far. Thanks for any help/advice!

```
   public static boolean balancedTree(String s) throws InvalidTreeSyntax {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(') {
            
            stack.push(c);
            
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') { 

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more test cases, the one you have provided in the question only has one child. How will the input look if you have two child for a?

Comment: @RohanSharma Sorry about that, in the case of a simple tree with one root and two children it should look like this: (a(g)(b)) where 'a' is the root and 'g' and 'b' are the children. I'm just trying to do it as simple as possible for now.

Comment: Did you try the approach where you put the alphabets as well in your stack and when you encounter a closing bracket you first take out the alphabet and then check if top has a opening bracket

Comment: Also consider for example that a does not have any right child, in that case does the input looks this (a(g)) or this (a(g)())?

Comment: @RohanSharma Hi Rohan! If there is no child and the user enters an empty pair of parenthesis, it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure you know what the syntax is:

```
    tree: /* empty */
        | '(' letter tree tree ')'

    letter: 'a' | 'b' | ... | 'z'
```

Then your parser should actually construct a tree. It is obviously a recursive function that'd do this. The whole string is correct when the top-most call of your function consumes all the input.